# How can I select in with same order of values

Tags: sql

I have a question.

I have a tabel of ProductId, ProductName.

inside it. I have

```
                  1-A
                  2-B
                  3-C
                  4-D
```

IF I do `select * from products where Id IN (1,2,3,4)`

I Get B,D,C,A How Can I get A,B,C,D

Comment: use order by, select * from products where Id IN (1,2,3,4) order by ProductName

Comment: o what if I type 3,2,4,1 then I need C,B,D,A

Comment: Do you want a custom order?

Comment: no if i say select * from products where Id IN (3,2,4,1) I need C,B,D,A

Comment: Basically you can't make it order the lines based on your IN statement. You have to use an ORDER BY clause

Comment: The WHERE clause just defines _which_ rows to return, not the order. If you want a specific order, you need to do ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

use `order by`

```
select * from tablename order by ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need another table.

```
SELECT p.* FROM PRODUCTS p
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 3 as id, 1 as ord
union all
SELECT 2 as id, 2  
union all
SELECT 4 as id, 3  
union all
SELECT 1 as id, 4   
) O
on o.id=P.productID
order by o.ord
```

Comment: What if I have 1000 rows in my table.

Comment: If the IDs you want are in a table then it's a different question and different answer.  Happy to help out but you'll need to explain further.  Bear in mind that the IDs in *that* table won't have an order, so you need to explain a) where your IDs are and b) how to establish the order you want.